# Unable to post a product with images using WooCommerce NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have been trying to insert a product using nodejs woocommerce api (v3) with the code below. However, the code only works when I remove the marked  section. Otherwise I get the error code 400.

```
var WooCommerce = require('woocommerce');

var wooCommerce = new WooCommerce({
  url: 'http://mysite',
  consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXX',
  secret: 'cs_XXXXXX'
});

var data = {
  product: {
    title: 'Product',
    regular_price: '21.99',
    description: 'This is an awesome product', 

    //################ WORKS WHEN THIS SECTION IS REMOVED ##############

    images: [
      {
        src: 'http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg',
        position: 0
      }
    ]

    //###################################################################

  }
};

wooCommerce.post('/products', data, function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

How can I add images to the product along with this API call? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's only `image`? not `images`? have you tried that?

Comment: do you have access to any server-side logs? are the images you are trying to upload accessible directly? are the permissions for the upload-folder set properly?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
var value = Object.assign(product, images)
data = value;
```

I think as along as your arrays are one to one this could work.  Or you could simply just create your own object and plugin the values as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the keys fixed the problem!

```
var WooCommerce = require('woocommerce');

var wooCommerce = new WooCommerce({
  url: 'http://mysite',
  consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXX',
  secret: 'cs_XXXXXX'
});

var data = {
  "product": {
    "title": 'Product',
    "regular_price": '21.99',
    "description": 'This is an awesome product', 

    //##################################################################

    "images": [
      {
        "src": 'http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg',
        "position": 0
      }
    ]

    //###################################################################

  }
};

wooCommerce.post('/products', data, function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```